# LibreOffice Calc "Find" command matches row indices

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I wanted to search a certain value in a column, so I naturally selected the column, CTRL+F, and entered the value to the box. However, LibreOffice matches all cells with a row index containing my number (e.g. for 12 it matches rows 12, 112, 120, 121, etc). How can I make it not to do this, and only match the cell values? Is this a feature or a bug?

Edit: Said column contained formulas, after "burning" in the values the matches are correct. Nevertheless, I think this counts as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, enable `Current select only`. Press Find Next or Find All. Only the cells containing 12 on the column (current selection) will be found.

[image]

Comment: Searching via this dialog is the same for me (even if I only select some cells, and not the full column), it still matches row indices. What version is your LibreOffice? Mine is 7.0.5.2.

Comment: @Rolf I have tried it with versions 7.0.0.3 and 7.2.0.4. They both work as expected. No bug.